# Characterising a relation between two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say we have a $3\times 3$ matrix $\mathbf{M}$ and vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that:

$$\mathbf{Mu}_i=\mathbf{v}_i,\quad i=1,2,3$$

where $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_3$ are linearly independent. Let $\mathbf{U}$ be the matrix whose columns are $\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2,\mathbf{u}_3$.

What is the relationship between $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{U}?$

My thoughts where, that if we constructed $\mathbf{V}$ in the same manner, we would have $\mathbf{MU}=\mathbf{V}$. But I am not sure whether I've answered the question/whether there is something more that can be said. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. $\mathbf{MU=V}$, and, if $\mathbf M$ is invertible, $\mathbf{U=M^{-1}V}$.

Additionally, since $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Then, $M$ is invertible if and only if $M$ is a transition matrix, and in this case, $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ also form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thanks. Can anything else can be said?

Comment: Since $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ are linearly independent, $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  If $M$ is invertible, then $M$ is a transition matrix, and if $M$ is a transition matrix, then $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @NicholasStull Yes, that's true. Please do edit the answer and add that in there.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Your answer is sufficient (as I only gave an equivalent statement), but I have edited that in for clarity.

Comment: @NicholasStull Thanks!